# LinkButton Click Event in Repeater Nested Datalist in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, repeater, datalist, linkbutton

I have such kind of a design in a project. How can I reach button click event in repeater nested datalist in asp.net?

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlPosts" runat="server" Width="100%" RepeatLayout="Flow" 
RepeatColumns="1" OnItemCommand="dlPosts_ItemCommand" 
OnItemDataBound="dlPosts_ItemDataBound">
 <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Repeater ID="repImgs" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
     <img src="<%#Eval("Picture") %>"  style="height: 35px; width: 35px" alt="" align="middle" valign="top" />
     <asp:LinkButton ID="lbYorum" runat="server" class="w3-btn w3-green w3-hover-orange" CommandName="MyUpdate" CommandArgument='<%#Bind("YazarID") %>'> Send</asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
   </asp:Repeater>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just attach ***OnCommand*** event to LinkButton like regular button control.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lbYorum" runat="server" 
    class="w3-btn w3-green w3-hover-orange" 
    CommandName="MyUpdate" 
    CommandArgument='<%#Bind("YazarID") %>' 
    OnCommand="lbYorum_Command"> Send</asp:LinkButton>
```

### Code Behind

Then retrieve `YazarID` from `e.CommandArgument`.

```
protected void lbYorum_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string commandName = e.CommandName;
    string yazarID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
}
```

### * Update *

> if I add a new TextBox in repeater, how can I get the value of it?

You can use ***Parent.FindControl*** to find sibling controls.

```
...

<ItemTemplate>
    <img src="<%#Eval("Picture") %>" style="height: 35px; width: 35px" alt="" align="middle" valign="top" />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbYorum" runat="server" 
        class="w3-btn w3-green w3-hover-orange" 
        CommandName="MyUpdate" 
        CommandArgument='<%#Bind("YazarID") %>' 
        OnCommand="lbYorum_Command"> Send</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtYorum" runat="server" Height="50" Width="500" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
...

protected void lbYorum_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    string commandName = e.CommandName;
    string yazarID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();

    var control = sender as Control;
    var txtYorum = control.Parent.FindControl("txtYorum") as TextBox;
}
```

Comment: if I add a new TextBox in repeater, how can I get the value of it? <asp:TextBox ID="txtYorum" runat="server" height="50" width="500" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>